# Setting default argument value in Racket

Tags: racket, default-value

Is it possible to set a default value to some of arguments in Racket?

Like so in Python:

```
def f(arg=0)
    ...
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes; take a look at: [declaring optional arguments](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html#%28part._.Declaring_.Optional_.Arguments%29).

For example:

```
(define (f [arg 0])
  (* arg 2))
```

Racket also supports functions with keyword arguments.  The link should lead to documentation that talks about them too.  Good luck!

Comment: Btw, do you think it's a good idea to use optional arguments for passing state in recursive functions?

Comment: Sometimes, but it often backfires on me.  If the optional argument is some accumulator, for example, then if I forget to pass the accumulator in my recursive call somewhere, well, oops.  :)

Comment: wrt the use of optional arguments for storing state in recursive functions, I see that as a slight evil in that you're abstraction is leaky.  I prefer the pattern with an inner-define like so: (define (foo a b c) (define (foo a b c state) #|...|#) (foo a b c 'init-state))

Comment: That what I was thinking about. But, damn, (define (foo a b c [state '()])) is so much easier to type :)

Comment: Use a name-let.

    (define (tree-sum t)
      (let loop ([t t])
        (if (tree-node? t) 
          (apply + (map loop (tree-children t))))
          (tree-val t))))

Then you can add whichever state arguments you need to the loop function without leaking them into the interface of the tree-sum function.
@Halst

Comment: How to make the argument optional *and* a keyword argument, like it actually is in the OP?